# Cakephp Acl error

Tags: cakephp, acl

I try to use alaxos acl plugin for study of Acl code 
and I got error

```
Warning (512): AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array
(
    [Aro0.model] => Group
    [Aro0.foreign_key] => admin
)
" [CORE\cake\libs\model\db_acl.php, line 191]
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node         references:
Aro: Array
(
   [User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 76
        [username] => tttttt
        [group_id] => admin
        [active] => 1
        [activation_code] => 
        [widget_count] => 
        [lastvisit] => 
    )

)

Aco: Users/add [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 273]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\cake\libs\debugger.php:673) [CORE\cake\libs\
```

[My Db picture here](http://uppic.net/full/172552a7a7e5c52bff6e128c817456c9)
[User and Group Model](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1487997553)
thank for answer

Comment: Should the `Aro0.foreign_key` be `admin`? the `foreign_key` field is an integer in the table schema. Might not be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to set basic require data in database 
it important for acl component to work right